# Managing multiple views for a Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm creating a Backbone app with a section to view reports; the section has three parts: a menu of report links, the title of the displayed report, and the content of the displayed report. The user is to click on a report link, which will fetch the associated model's data. Then the report title and content should update accordingly. However, I'm not sure how the view bindings should work, and each report may return slightly different data that requires a different view template. Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8ys5/1/) (fetch method overridden just for this example)

Right now, I have a Backbone model for each report and a Backbone collection of all the reports:

```
App.Models.Report = Backbone.Model.extend();

App.Collections.Reports = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: App.Models.Report,
    url: "/reports"
});
```

The menu view is tied to the collection and on click, sets `App.State.title` and `App.State.cid`, which the other two views are listening to:

```
App.Views.ReportLink = Backbone.View.extend({
     tagName: 'li',
     className: 'is-clickable',

     initialize: function() {
             this.render();
     },

     render: function() {
         this.el.innerHTML = this.model.get('title');
         this.$el.attr('data-CID', this.model.cid); // store the model's cid
     }
});

App.Views.ReportMenu = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'ul',

    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render)
        this.render();

        this.$el.on('click', 'li', function() {
            App.State.set({
                'title': this.innerHTML,
                'cid': $(this).attr('data-CID') // cid of the clicked view's model
            });
        });
    },
```

The difficulty is with the report content; what it currently does is listen for changes to `App.State.cid` and then calls fetch on the given model with that cid. This fetch populates the model with a sub-collection of report rows. The report content view then set its html based on the sub-collection data, and it is also supposed to apply the correct template to the data:

```
App.Views.ReportContent = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(attrs) {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:cid', this.render);
        this.reportsCollection = attrs.reportsCollection;
    },

    render: function() {
        var self = this,
            cid = this.model.get('cid'),
            model = this.reportsCollection.get(cid);

        model.fetch({
            success: function() {
                var html = '';

                model.subCollection.each(function(model) {
                    var template = _.template($('#templateReportA').html()); // want to dynamically set this
                    html += template(model.toJSON());
                });

                self.$el.html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

1) Is this the correct sort of implementation for this type of multiple view situation with a collection?

2) How can I pass the correct template that needs to apply for each individual report? Right now I'm explicitly passing the view template for report A. I can think of storing it on the model but the template should be associated with the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `cid`s are all made up of characters that are legal in HTML `id`s, then a simple solution would be to name all your report templates `templateReportxxx` where "xxx" is the report's `cid` and then just change the template-loading line to

```
var template = _.template($('#templateReport'+cid).html());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the simple solution! I implemented it and then changed all my `cid` references to `id`s so that I can control the references.